# Как отловить событие, что пользователь в группе телеграм пригласил человека в чат

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Появилась идея по приглашению людей в чат и после подсчета количества учатников, которых пользователь пригласил.

Не могу понять, есть ли возможность сделать такое?

Пишу на python aiogram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты не можешь отлавливать приглашения человека конкретным пользователем, но ты можешь отлавливать момент присоединения участника к чату